# jQuery UI sortable: how to leave css values of changed items untouched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a list with z-indexes set in reverse order:

```
<ul>
    <li style="z-index: 3;">First item</li>
    <li style="z-index: 2;">Second item</li>
    <li style="z-index: 1;">Third item</li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery UI sortable I want to achieve the effect when z-indexes of my elements don't change when I sort the items. Say, I want to sort all represented items in this order: Second, Third, First. But leave z-indexes untouched!

Thanks.

This is what I've achieved with JS so far (I'm all new in this):

```
$('#widget-2').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.data('originIndex', ui.item.css('z-index'));
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.data('placeholderIndex', ui.placeholder.css('z-index'));

            var originIndex = ui.item.data('originIndex');
            var placeholderIndex = ui.item.data('placeholderIndex');

            ui.placeholder.css('z-index', originIndex);
            ui.item.css('z-index', placeholderIndex);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `z-index` works only for `positioned` elements

Comment: Edited my answer check it

Comment: Related (sort of) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345132/reversing-z-index-based-from-page-render-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already use JavaScript on the page, I would suggest you calculate and assign `z-index` on document ready, using this tiny jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.reverseZIndex = function () {
    // get the children of the list.
    var $children = this.children(),
        length = $children.length;

    $children.each(function (index) {
        // assign z-index, high values to low.
        this.style.zIndex = length - index;
    });

    return this;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $widget2 = $('#widget-2');

    // calculate reversed z-index.
    $widget2.reverseZIndex();

    // initialize sortable.
    $widget2.sortable(...);
});
```

Then you can use this plugin on any given list, `<ul>` or `<ol>` (or even a parent `<div>`), so the children will have `z-index` in the reversed order.

Do the same in jQuery sortable on `change`, to update `z-index`:

```
$widget2.sortable({
    ...
    change: function () {
       ...
       $widget2.reverseZIndex();
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works flawlessly. I just had to change change method to stop in sortable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Use`nth` child http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvEdMw

HTML

```
<ul>
<li >aaa</li>
<li>aaaasdsd</li>
<li>fgf</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
 background-color:orange;
 }

li:nth-child(n-3){
color:red;
}

li:nth-child(n+2){
color:blue;
} 

li:nth-child(n+3){
color:green;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('ul').sortable();
```

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you. But there's one problem, I don't know how many elements my list would has, there can be 10 or 100.

Comment: @vadimyer if you are using two colors then you can set it to `li:nth-child(odd)` or `even`

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use z-indexes.

Comment: @vadimyer you can use `z-index`

Comment: I have box-shadows and need them to be on top of each next element. But I'd love to vote up for your solution, though.

Comment: @vadimyer i am not able to do the same thing with `z-index` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvEdMw i am going to ask about this here

Comment: This is a solution for now, thank you. But I might need 100, or even 500 elements, the idea to hardcode those nth-childs in CSS doesn't seem good. I'm still trying to understand how could it be done with JS.