# How to reverse the order of zindex in the whole site

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I want to reverse the z-index of my website, so that objects with lower z-index are on top of objects with higher z-index - is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Not really, because a lot of z-indexes are dynamic and not explicitly set by the css author

Comment: are the z-index added as `style attribute` or as `css-property`?

Comment: try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345132/reversing-z-index-based-from-page-render-order

Comment: @tacoshy style attribute

Comment: then simply get all elements and with a z-index and multiply their `z-index` with `* -1`

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to achieve? I'm struggling to think of any way this could be useful.

Comment: For flat sibling elements structure in single container it could work "as expected", but for nested containers with z-indexes scattered in various depths I'm afraid it is not technically possible to get what you possibly expect (to look at those stack "from below"). Stacking context will prevent it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454901/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-nested-child-elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard solutions, but you can always write a custom function to do it. Check if this works for you:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', reverseZIndex);

function reverseZIndex(){
  // Get all body elements
  Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*'))

  // Reverse those that have z-index
  .forEach((elem, idx) => {
    const zIndex = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('z-index');
    if (zIndex !== 'auto' && zIndex != 0) {
      elem.style.zIndex = zIndex * -1;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;

}

.z {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.z1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
}

.z2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
}

.z3 {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
}

.z4 {
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 60px;
  left: 15px;
}

.z5 {
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: red;
  top: 80px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Reverse z-index</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="z z1"></div>
  <div class="z z2"></div>
  <div class="z z3"></div>
  <div class="z z4"></div>
  <div class="z z5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that might work for your case is to dynamically, re-write the style sheet(s) using javascript.

Style sheets are html elements like any other and live references to them can be made using:

```
styleSheets = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
```

this creates a live `html collection` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). If you have a single style sheet it is referenced in index[0], additional style sheets have incremented indices. Cricially, the `innerHTML` of the collection can be modified as for any other element and, because the reference is 'live', changes to it are automatically applied to the html tree displayed in the browser.

The following example takes the `innerHTML` of the style sheet and splits it into an array of lines. `Array.map` is used to examine each line for the presence of a `z-index` rule. If present, the numerical value following it is extracted and multiplied by -1 so the largest value becomes the smallest and vice versa. Other lines are left unaltered. The check and multiplication is performed using a `ternary operator` conditional, but you could equally loop through the lines with a `for` loop.

The results of the mapping are joined as new lines and the resulting string used to replace the `innerHTML` of the style sheet.
This working snippet applies a custom `reverseZ` function to the style sheet each time the page is clicked. If you have several style sheets, interation through the collection will achieve the same result.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', reverseZ);
const styleSheet = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];

function reverseZ() {
const lines = styleSheet.innerHTML.split("\n");
const newLines = lines.map(line => {

 return (line.indexOf('z-index') > -1) ? `z-index: ${parseInt(line.slice(line.indexOf(':')+1, line.indexOf(';')))*-1};`: line;

});

styleSheet.innerHTML = newLines.join("\n");


} // end function reverseZ
```

```css
div {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
aspect-ratio: 1;
border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.red {
background: red;
z-index: -100;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.orange {
background: orange;
z-index: -70;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}
.yellow {
background: yellow;
z-index: -10;
top: 40px;
left: 40px;
}
.green {
background: green;
z-index: 0;
top: 60px;
left: 60px;
}
.blue {
background: blue;
z-index: 20;
top: 80px;
left: 80px;
}
.indigo {
background: indigo;
z-index: 50;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
}
.violet {
background: violet;
z-index: 100;
top: 120px;
left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">click</div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="indigo"></div>
<div class="violet">click</div>
```